# Is it possible to design the html from form builder

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I made select form in buildForm()

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('icon','entity',
            array(
            'class' => 'UserBundle:IconPics',
            'property' => 'label', 
            'expanded' => true,
            'data' => $defaultIcon,
            'multiple' => false,    
            'label' => 'form.icon',
             'query_builder' => function ($repository) {
                return $repository->createQueryBuilder('i')
                ->add('where', 'i.enabled = true');
             },

    ));
```

in twig.

```
{{ form_widget(form.icon) }}
```

it shows the radiobutton selector html like this.

```
<div id="fos_user_registration_form_icon">
    <input type="radio" id="fos_user_registration_form_icon_3" name="fos_user_registration_form[icon]" required="required" value="3" checked="checked" />
    <label for="fos_user_registration_form_icon_3" class="required">male</label>
    <input type="radio" id="fos_user_registration_form_icon_4" name="fos_user_registration_form[icon]" required="required" value="4" />
    <label for="fos_user_registration_form_icon_4" class="required">female</label>
    <input type="radio" id="fos_user_registration_form_icon_5" name="fos_user_registration_form[icon]" required="required" value="5" />
    <label for="fos_user_registration_form_icon_5" class="required">old male</label>
    <input type="radio" id="fos_user_registration_form_icon_6" name="fos_user_registration_form[icon]" required="required" value="6" />
</div>
```

However,this html is not cool,just align the radio button.
I would like to  design this html.
such as using table or something

```
<table><tr>
<td>Button1</td>
<td>label</td>
</tr></table>
```

Is it possible?

---

Thanks for your reply

I have read the link and choose the most simple way.

put this at the top of twig and made some progress.

But I am facing two problems

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
{% block radio_widget %}
<td>
<input type="radio" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}/>
</td>
{% endblock radio_widget %}
```

it shows the html like this

```
<td style="border-style:none;">
<input type="radio" id="fos_user_registration_form_icon_3" name="fos_user_registration_form[icon]" required="required" value="3"/></td>
<label for="fos_user_registration_form_icon_3" class="required">male</label>
```

1.problem

radio button is inside the td tag (good!!),but label is out side the

where does this label appears?????

how can I delete or control this???

I understood this label is defferent from the 'label' that  I can choose at the formBuilder.

2) problem

when I use 'checked' as sample says

```
 {% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %}
```

it says like this checked property is used in even normal 
form_div_layout.html.twig

I have no clue about this.

Please help me . thanks

```
Variable "checked" does not exist in FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig at line 7
500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the form theme in twig  by using your new form layout like

```
{% form_theme formObject 'NamespaceYourBundle:Form:form_div_layout.html.twig' %}
```

and in `form_div_layout.html.twig` redefine your field blocks like for radio button you can customize it

```
{% block radio_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
<td>
    <input type="radio" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />
</td>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock radio_widget %}
```

For label block you can use it like

```
{% block form_label %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if label is not sameas(false) %}
        {% if not compound %}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'for': id}) %} /* you can skip this part for td */
        {% endif %}
        {% if required %}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if label is empty %}
            {% set label = name|humanize %}
        {% endif %}
        <td {% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</td>
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_label %}
```

And now finally override the expanded widget

```
{% block choice_widget_expanded %}
{% spaceless %}
    <table {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
    {% for child in form %}
      <tr>
        {{ form_widget(child) }}
        {{ form_label(child) }}
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_expanded %}
```

**Edit** to override label block for `choice_widget_expanded`  you can define your block and use it like in below

```
{% block choice_widget_expanded %}
{% spaceless %}
    <table {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
    {% for child in form %}
      <tr>
        {{ form_widget(child) }}
        {{ form_label_custom(child) }}
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_expanded %}
```

And for the custom label too `form_label_custom` now for every choice field  with expanded property (not all fields) your new label will be in action

```
{% block form_label_custom %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if label is not sameas(false) %}
        {% if not compound %}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'for': id}) %} /* you can skip this part for td */
        {% endif %}
        {% if required %}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if label is empty %}
            {% set label = name|humanize %}
        {% endif %}
        <td {% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</td>
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_label_custom %}
```

[**How to customize Form Rendering**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)

Comment: Thanks your answer is great!!!I can made progress though,I bump into two problems,if you know please let me know.

Comment: @whitebear you have overrided only one block i.e radio in my answer i have overrided 3 blocks  `choice_widget_expanded ,form_label,radio_widget` you also have to override these blocks see in `choice_widget_expanded` block there is loop and i have opened table on it and inside the loop tr is opened label is rendered through label block hope it makes sense

Comment: ah, I see. I have done some tests and understood the choice_widget_expanded and form_label is relevant with this problem. However if you change form_label or choice_widget_expanded, it affects every items in this form objects right? Is there any way to make it affect only a certain member object?

Comment: thanks, M Khalid Junaid. your answer sloved my first quesion. I have made another.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744018/overriding-the-form-rendering-template-according-to-the-items

Comment: AH, you gave me more answer,I will challenge this and report here.

Comment: I posted there too :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Form theming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-theming).

You have to create fields.html.twig and include into yout twig file like:

{% form_theme form with 'AcmeTaskBundle:Form:fields.html.twig' %}

In fileds.html.twig add radio widget ([check out](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig)). Here you can now add tables, divs etc. Inside {% block radio_widget %}.

```
{% block radio_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <input type="radio" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock radio_widget %}
```