# Custom form theme breaks Form::modelData property in Symfony 2

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

> *OP note: it was simply that `li` elements aren't passed through in forms which I forgot about.*
>
> For context please see my [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545829/how-can-i-render-an-entity-choice-select-field-as-a-ul-field-in-twig/28562153#28562153) on how I required the ability to change `select` and `option` tags to `ul` an `li` tags when rendering a dropdown with Symfony 2 forms as they look and work well with my CSS framework of choice.

As a result of changing how my form element is rendered, it seems that the data is no longer coming through after submitting.

I am overriding the `{% choice_widget_* %}` parts of the `choice` field in order to change these to `ul` and `li`s. Here is my change:

```
{%- block choice_widget_collapsed -%}
    {%- if required and empty_value is none and not empty_value_in_choices and not multiple -%}
        {% set required = false %}
    {%- endif -%}
    <ul {{ block('widget_attributes') }}>
        {%- if preferred_choices|length > 0 -%}
            {% set options = preferred_choices %}
            {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
            {%- if choices|length > 0 and separator is not none -%}
                <li disabled="disabled">{{ separator }}</li>
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endif -%}
        {%- set options = choices -%}
        {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
    </ul>
{%- endblock choice_widget_collapsed -%}

{%- block choice_widget_options -%}
    {% for group_label, choice in options %}
        {%- if choice is iterable -%}
            <optgroup label="{{ group_label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}">
                {% set options = choice %}
                {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
            </optgroup>
        {%- else -%}
            <li value="{{ choice.value }}"{% if choice is selectedchoice(value) %} selected="selected"{% endif %}><a href="#">{{ choice.label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</a></li>
        {%- endif -%}
    {% endfor %}
{%- endblock choice_widget_options -%}
```

I found and modified this code from [Symfony 2 github source](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L54-L85), and it allowed me to render my form as such:

[image]

**The problem**: When submitting this form, the "target" field comes through fine, but my overriding seems to have corrupted how the data is retrieved from the dropdown and my debugging shows empty data fields.

Here's the break line in `setDefaultOptions()` within my type:

[image: breakline]

Here's the form data. Please note how the modelData does indeed exist for "target', which is a standard input field, and how the modelData does not exist for the locator dropdown (highlighted):

[image: wtf]

So the data is coming through as null because of how I've changed how the form is rendered, but **what can I do about this**?

Can I place some sort of adapter or data transformer to handle this change? What needs to be done? I can imagine this happening with anyone who wants to theme their own form and remove some of the annoying divs that are injected by symfony during rendering. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<li></li>` elements are *not* form elements (and thus won't get submitted with the form).

You would need to add a form submit handler (using javascript) that turns the li elements back into some sort of form elements.

Ideally you would transform them back to the `<option></option>` elements so you don't need a data-transformer on the server.

jQuery boilerplate code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myForm1").submit(function() {
        //Gets fired when the form is about to be submitted, but before the actual request
        $("#myForm1").append("<optgroup name=.......");          
        $("ul[name=\"somebundle_formname_fieldname\"]").children("li").each(function () {
            $("#myForm1").find("<optgroup name=.......").append("<option value=" + $(this).attr("value") +">bla</option>");
        });
    });
});
```

Vanilla JS (IE9+, Chrome, Firefox) boilerplate code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var myForm1 = document.getElementById("myForm1");
    myForm1.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        //Gets fired when the form is about to be submitted, but before the actual request
        var tmpOptGroup = document.createElement("optgroup");
        tmpOptGroup.name = "somebundle_formname_fieldname";
        myForm1.appendChild(tmpOptGroup);

        var liElements = document.querySelectorAll("ul[name=\"somebundle_formname_fieldname\"] li");
        for(var i=0;i<liElements.length;i++) {
            var currentLiElement = liElements[i];
            //add option, see jquery above
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is great, and I can't believe I missed that! What do you think about putting in some hidden form `select` and `option` elements and merely populating the right one with the selected value before submitting?

Comment: I added *vanilla* javascript code for those that don't want to use jquery.